# Python Regex to find particular in sentence

Tags: python, regex

I am very new to regex I am searching in following sentence:

`OCEU0H - Debt securities issued by multilateral development company
a. OCEU0J - Debt securities issued by private company`

Out should be :-
`['OCEU0H','OCEU0J']`

`OC` is always at start and `EU` will be any input country code.

My try is :-
`r'\b+(^(OC)\W+)\b+'`

Also please suggest me the best tutorial or document for regex.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use

```
\bOC\w+\b
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/BQ8WH2/1)

To match word chars, you need to use `\w`, not `\W`. Note that if you only want to match ASCII letters after `OC`, it makes more sense to use `[A-Za-z]` rather than `\w` (any letter, digit or `_`).

You should not quantify zero-width assertions like `\b` (word boundaries) and should not use the `^` anchor before `OC` as `^` matches the start of sting.

**Pattern details**

- `\b` - a word boundary
- `OC` - a literal substring
- `\w+` - 1 or more word chars (or any 1+ ASCII letter if you use `[A-Za-z]+`)
- `\b` - a word boundary

Comment: For Python 3, your comments about `\w` only supporting ASCII is only true if the `ASCII` flag is in effect.  In Python 3 matches are Unicode by default for strings, not ASCII.  In the default case, `\w` is  not equivalent to `[A-Za-z0-9_]`.

Comment: @cdarke There is no mentioning of Python version. I can add more if that detail is provided. I did not say anything about `\w` supporting ASCII, BTW, just if OP wants to only match any 1+ ASCII letters, OP should use `[A-Za-z]+`.

Comment: That's true, on SO the default python version is assumed to be 3.  However, I think in this case it probably does not matter to the OP, it was just a note for future viewers of your post.